# Paint null or no data values with MapboxGL JS using setPaintProperty for circle-color and stops arrays

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm currently painting on my map a circle vector-tile layer from Geoserver with the use of stops in the setPaintProperty method as follow:

```
this.objectMap.setPaintProperty(layerName, 'circle-color', {
    "property": 'fieldname',
    "stops": [
      ...this.frequenciesService.intervalStops[ms] // using the stop format
    ]
  })
```

How can I do to paint values outside the stops values (as no-data or null values)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the **default** property for functions (https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/pull/4175):

```
this.objectMap.setPaintProperty(layerName, 'circle-color', {
  "property": 'fieldname',
  "stops": [
    ...this.frequenciesService.intervalStops[ms] // using the stop format
  ],
  "default": "yourDefaultValue"
})
```

Comment: The default value seems to ignore null and undefined. But we were able to use coalesce to tell mapbox-gl to treat null values as 0 and then we have a color set for 0:
```['coalesce', ['get', 'height'], 0]```